# вывести однофамильцев sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть 3 таблицы. пусть t1, t2, t3. занесены фамилии в поле last_name. и как вывести тогда количество всех однофамильцем.
по типу:

```
иванов 12
петров 26
Сидоров 3
```

помимо этих таблиц есть таблицы, связывающих их
t12 (по id связывают таблицы 1 и 2), t23 (по id связывают таблицы 2 и 3)

upd:
такой вариант. вроде правильный

```
SELECT s.last_name, count(*)  FROM Parents p
left join StPar sp on sp.id_p=p.id_p
left join Students s on s.id_student=sp.id_s
left join StStaff ss on ss.id_s=s.id_student
left join Staff st on ss.id_st=st.id_staff
group by s.last_name 
having count(*) > 1
```

вопрос таков. можно ли из этого сделать запрос с подзапросом?)

Comment: Почитайте про group by, count. Запрос не сложный, лучше самому разобраться раз, чем каждый раз спрашивать

Comment: Если "в 3х таблицах разные люди", то сначала надо объединить выборки фамилий (UNION), а потом агрегировать. Или агрегировать по каждой таблице отдельно, потом UNION и финальная агрегация (текст длиннее, но выполняться может быстрее).

Comment: Замените словесное описание структуры на соответствующие CREATE TABLE (неиспользуемые для решения задачи поля можно пропустить) с примером данных и требуемым результатом строго для показанных данных. Чётко определите, как отличать одного и того же человека в разных таблицах от однофамильца.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем такая связность?
Пробуйте что-то вроде (Пример для PG):

```
SELECT last_name, count(*)
FROM table
GROUP_BY last_name
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: потому что в 3х таблицах разные люди

Comment: Я, конечно, не видел структуры, но, наверное людей стоило бы поместить в одну таблицу и дифференцировать их по внешнему ключу какому-нибудь.

Comment: таблицы можно объединить через union